# Reference C# Variable in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, function, var

I have read quite a few threads but I cannot figure out why this will not work. I am creating a SharePoint Web Part that will serve as a navigation bar. Everything works great until I try and reference a C# Variable in the JS Code.

Here is my C# from the VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs:

```
    public class myClass
    {

        public string theValue = "hi";


    }
```

Here is the HTML/JS from the VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx Page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getMyValue() {

    var myVar = "<%= myClass.theValue %>";

    alert(myVar);
}
```

```
<li><a href="http://maindt" 
    onmouseover="getMyValue(), mopen('m1')"
    onmouseout="mclosetime()">MAINDT Home</a>
    <div id="m1" 
        onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()"
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">
    <a href="">Site 1</a>
    <a href="">Site 2</a>
    <a href="">Site 3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

What happens is when I hover my mouse over the "MaindDT Home" drop down, I get the alert(myVar) which is good but the content is <%=myClass.theValue%> when I'm expecting it to display the value of theValue which is "Hi"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is - if you try to store/access your variable in a separate js file - you simply can't; the aspx parser isn't running over js/css files.

Here's how I'd do it:

Your separate javascript file should look like this:

```
   // added a few parameters (id should be something like 'm1')
   function getMyValue(id, value)
   {
       alert(value); 
   }
```

And your ascx file should contain this:

```
<!-- add a reference to the js file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascriptFile.js"></script>

<%
    // in order for this to work:
    // it requires a field/property of type myClass within your page or theValue should be a static  property/field of myClass 

    // create an instance of myClass (or get it another way...)
    var myClassInstance = new myClass();

    // create a simple reference to the value you want (not required - but makes it a bit more readable)
    var myValue = myClassInstance.theValue;

    // I'm injecting myValue as a parameter for the javascript function (this gets printed as a string - so make sure you encode it properly)
%>      
<li><a href="http://maindt" 
    onmouseover="getMyValue('m1', '<%: myValue %>'); mopen('m1');"
    onmouseout="mclosetime()">MAINDT Home</a>
    <div id="m1" 
        onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()"
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">
    <a href="">Site 1</a>
    <a href="">Site 2</a>
    <a href="">Site 3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

A bit late, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I'm encountering an error and it seems to be with the line of code `onmouseover="getMyValue('m1', <%: myValue %>); mopen('m1');"`. The error is c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SPListWebPart\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx(27): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'

Comment: When I change it to `onmouseover="getMyValue('m1', <%= myValue %>); mopen('m1');"` I get the error: c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SPListWebPart\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx(21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oh, if <%: myValue %> is not working try <%= Server.HtmlEncode(myValue) %>, it practically does the same - but the earlier is only available for asp.net >= 4.0

Comment: Having said that, which version of asp.net are you currently using?

Comment: c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SPListWebPart\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx(21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm not sure hwo to figure out which version of asp.net I'm running. I'll get that figured out. I know my framework is 3.5 and I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Also, the Wizard or New Project Template i'm using is a C# Visual Web Part project...

Comment: If you're using .net 2.0 then var is not working - use the explicit type definition (string, myClass, etc.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32907/discussion-between-andreas-prechtl-and-mwilson)

Comment: @mwilson If you look at my answer at the bottom you problem is solved with one line right below your class declaration in your code behind

Comment: Update: for sharepoint webparts, codebehind seems to be a nogo - so we embedded a `<script runat="server"> /* ..  */ </script>` into the ascx directly in order to make it work...

Comment: Finally, I found something interesting about code-behind and sharepoint webparts: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/06/28/creating-a-sharepoint-site-page-with-code-behind-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here example:

VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx

```
 <script>
     function getMyValue() {
           var myVar = <%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this.theValue) %>';
           alert(myVar); 
     }
 </script>
 <li><a href="http://maindt" 
        onmouseover="getMyValue('m1'), mopen('m1')"
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">MAINDT Home</a>
        <div id="m1" 
            onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()"
            onmouseout="mclosetime()">
               <a href="">Site 1</a>
               <a href="">Site 2</a>
               <a href="">Site 3</a>
        </div>
 </li>
```

Note, JavaScriptSerializer is used to correctly escape data to javascript. this also allow safely to pass nulls, numbers booleans, string with (". ', \n) symbols or objects. As alternative, you can use other json serializer.

If your data do not require escaping, just you can write just '<%=this.theValue %>'

VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs:

```
public class VisualWebPart1UserControl: WebControl
{
    public string theValue = "hi"; 
}
```

<%= and <#= expression work in *.ascx and *.aspx files - because they generated dynamically.
.js, .html, .css files are static, as result expressions will not work.
As expression you can written on C#, where 'this' - instance of 
VisualWebPart1UserControl class. Visual Studio intellisense will guide you.

Comment: I see what you're getting at...I keep running into this error though.c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SPListWebPart\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx(21): error CS0103: The name 'myClass' does not exist in the current context

Comment: and then I use this.theValue.......c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SPListWebPart\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx(21): error CS0117: 'ASP._controltemplates_splistwebpart_visualwebpart1_visualwebpart1usercontrol_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'theValue'

Comment: ASP.NET complies your user control in a temporary directory. User controls notoriously have a bit of "catch up" to play with changes, a couple F5's will flush the temporary of the old complied class with your latest changes. Just something you have to do once in a while developing user controls.

Comment: I've done quite a few F5's but still consistently get the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: What'll happen if you just add theValue by using `<% string theValue = "hi"; %>` within the ascx file? Can you access it then?

Comment: would that be VisualWebPart1.cs? When I do `<% string theValue = "hi" %>` I get the expected alert but the context is still wrong. Is shows "undefined".

Comment: @mwilson You have problems with C# part of the control. In my answer I've add a field directly to VisualWebPart1UserControl class. In my MS Visual Studio  when I add new ascx control with name "VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx" to solution by wizard - it created code behind class matched to control name - "VisualWebPart1UserControl" class and NOT "myClass". Please create new ascx control by wizard and directly add new field into created class.

Answer (score 1):

Your getMyValue() should be inlined with the asp/aspx page. And you have to make myClass.theValue static to access it directly.

Comment: If I just do `var myVar = "Hi";` it works. So how do I reference the C# variable `theValue`?

Comment: If you are having a separate JS file, make your function like:
  function getMyValue(theValue) {
           var myVar = theValue;
           alert(myVar); 
     }

Then have it in the aspx file like:

onmouseover="getMyValue('m1', '<%= myClass.theValue %>');

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Comment: My answer is the direction to solution.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your javascript resides inline in the ascx file.

In the VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs right under the class declaration you need to declare a variable like so:

protected MyClassInstance = new myClass();

This creates an instance of your class that, thanks to the accessor keyword "protected" can be read/accessed by your ascx page.