# not able to import the backend namespace from javascript to call the method

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a c# model class as follows

```
public Class Organisation.Employee{


 public int Id {get;set;}

 public string FirstName{get;set;}
 public string LastName {get;set;}
 public string salary {get;set;}
 public List<string> Roles {get;set;}

}
```

i want to call the javascript in such a way that i can import the namespace and uses the property like ${Employee.Firstname} in html page

My Javascript look like this but i don't how how to reference the namespace and call the backend.

```
<script type="server/javascript">
     importNamespace(Organisation.Employee)
     const id = request.getParameter('id')
     const employee = Employee.Lookup(id)
    </script>
```

Comment: What does `importNamespace` do?

Comment: I think this answer here might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477138/reference-c-sharp-variable-in-javascript